# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'orderby'

Tags: sql, azure, join, pyspark, union

I am using azure databrick on my application.
And I use ML to perform imputation. After I had the result, I want to join & union to make it a complete dataset so that I can write it to the blob storage.

```
df3 = spark.sql("""

select * from df1 
FULL OUTER JOIN df2 
on df1.columnindex == df2.columnindex

""")
```

After I finished with joining, I displayed the result and saw a lot of indexes in the 'columnindex' are missing, so I perform orderBy

```
df3 = df3.orderBy('columnindex')
```

It seems to me that the indexes are not missing, but not properly sorted.
But after I perform union

```
df5 = spark.sql("""

select * from unmissing_data 
union
select * from df4

""")
```

and perform orderBy

```
df5  = df5.orderBy('columnindex')
```

I get the following error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'orderby'. Does anyone know why this happens & why my initial indexes in the column 'columnindex' are not properly sorted as I had in my original dataset?

Comment: Also I tried before joining using df = df1.join(df2, key = ['columnindex'], on = 'outer'). After I perform several joins & unions, I can't run a second ML model and get a JVM out of heap memory error. Would be much appreciated if anyone could tell me why

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this in Spark version 3.2.0. and I think it may be a bug. Using `sort` in place of `orderBy` fixed the issue.